# Not receiving correct data at PHP server when sending an HTTP POST Request from iOS 9 / Swift 2.0

Tags: php, ios, swift, post, ios9

When i post **"username=abc&password=xyz"** from iOS using Swift to index.php, on my server i must receive

`$_POST["username"]` //"abc"

`$_POST["password"]` //"xyz"

**but i am receiving**

`$_POST["username"]` //Optional("abc")

`$_POST["password"]` //Optional("xyz")

**Finding trouble in figuring out the error. Kindly suggest a suitable solution.**

**Note:** `I am using Xcode 7.0.1, Swift 2.0, Simulator: iPhone 5, Deployment Target: iOS 9.0, Server = "Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11";`

Here's my swift code

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:"http://192.168.1.7/testSwiftPOST/index.php")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=abc&password=xyz"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let Data = data {
            print(NSString(data: Data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!) // this prints the data of the $_POST variable in the debug area
        }
}
task.resume()
```

Here's my php code

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
```

Here's my output in Xcode's debug area:

```
Array
(
    [username] => Optional("abc")
    [password] => Optional("xyz")
)
```

FYI (For Your Information), I have also added the following setting in my info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>192.168.1.7/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The above code worked perfectly in Xcode 6 with iOS 8.4 but the problem started after upgrading to Xcode 7 with iOS 9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataUsingEncoding` returns an optional. You must unwrap it before sending it in a request

```
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, your solution worked for me. But i found a strange thing, now the problem code i posted above is also working perfectly without any changes. Just wondering how iOS development can go bonkers sometimes!!!